# AllowOverride for .htaccess on local machine giving 403 Forbidden

Tags: apache, configuration

I have a mod_rewrite I'd like to use locally on my mac but when I change my configuration to in my directory tag I get a 403 Forbidden error. I've tried all the other solutions around but no luck.

Maybe somebody will see something I am not...

Here is the code:

httpd.conf

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory "/Library/WebServer/Documents/">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Which is overridden by myusername.conf

```
<Directory /Users/adrianmaurer/Sites/www>
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Virtual host file httpd-vhosts.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
DocumentRoot /Library/WebServer/Documents
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /Users/adrianmaurer/Sites/www
    ServerName myserver.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I'm having the same problem. If I set AllowOverride to All in "/etc/apache2/users/username.conf", I start getting 403 forbidden errors on my sites for that user. If I set it back to none, the errors go away.

Comment: went back to using nginx but I am glad you found a solution

Answer (score 27):

I was able to get it fixed by setting my /etc/apache2/users/username.conf file like so (Note you have to change the Options line too, not just the AllowOverride):

```
<Directory "/Users/tlhunter/Sites/">
    Options All               
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: so simple, I wish I could +2 this . . .