# PHP/mysql requiring 127.0.0.1 on OS X Mavericks

Tags: php, mysql, osx-mavericks

On Mac OS X 10.6, I am able to connect to mysql in php with

```
$mysql = mysql_connect(localhost,user,password)
```

However, if I use the same in Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks), I get the error message:

```
Warning: mysql_connect(): No such file or directory
```

if I use `$mysql = mysql_connect("127.0.0.1",user,password)`, it works OK, but I'd rather not make the change everywhere.

I've read on this site that there is a socket issue, but I already have this in `php.ini.default: pdo_mysql.default_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock`

Any idea on how to make `mysql_connect(localhost,user,password) work on 10.9` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please read those articles:

1. http://www.coolestguidesontheplanet.com/downtown/get-apache-mysql-php-and-phpmyadmin-working-osx-109-mavericks
2. [AllowOverride for .htaccess on local machine giving 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737048/allowoverride-for-htaccess-on-local-machine-giving-403-forbidden)
3. http://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/how-to-install-mcrypt-for-php-on-mac-osx-lion-10-7-development-server/
4. http://michaelgracie.com/2013/10/29/plugging-mcrypt-into-php-on-mac-os-x-mavericks-10-9/

Comment: Thanks. In the first article, I found the suggestion: mkdir /var/mysql; ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock This fixed the problem.

Comment: Me too. Brand new MacBook Air 2014 OS X 10.9. Conforming 1st article. Fix the 2002 socket error: `sudo mkdir /var/mysql` then comes `sudo ln -s /tmp/mysql.sock /var/mysql/mysql.sock` and finally `mysql.server restart`.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is to edit the hostnames file, but I am a PC user, so I can't walk you with that on mac. Anyway here is what I found and I suppose it is the same as your OS version

> Step 1 – Open the Terminal.app
>
> Either by start typing Terminal on the Spotlight, or by going into
>   Applications -> Utilities -> Terminal.
>
> Step 2 – Open the hosts file
>
> Open the hosts by typing on the Terminal that you have just opened:
>
> 1$ sudo nano /private/etc/hosts Type your user password when
>   prompted.
>
> Step 3 – Edit the hosts file
>
> The hosts file contains some comments (lines starting with the #
>   symbol), as well as some default hostname mappings (e.g. 127.0.0.1 –
>   localhost).
>   source: http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

what you need is to write an entry for 127.0.0.1 - localhost 
if it is not already there.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. The hosts file already had those entries:
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
fe80::1%lo0     localhost

Answer (score 0):

If you call `mysql_connect()` with `localhost` as a first argument PHP tries to connect using a UNIX domain socket instead of TCP.

Probably it looks for wrong socket name and/or you mysql only listens on TCP.

You should check your mysql settings (/etc/mysql ? search for socket) and the php `mysql.default_socket` config variable. (The `pdo_mysql.default_socket` you mentions is used when you connect using pdo.)

For example on my debian:

```
$ grep socket /etc/mysql/my.cnf 
socket          = /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock
```

(Otherwise your life would be easier if you use any kind of db abstraction layer, and storing the connection details only once.)

Comment: Thanks for idea. I located the file /usr/local/mysql-5.6.16-osx10.7-x86_64/my.cnf I found a line # socket = ..... that I replaced with socket = /tmp/mysql.sock I restarted mysql & apache, but problem was still there

Comment: I replaced "# socket = " by "socket = /tmp/mysql.sock" which meant I uncommented.