# Mod Rewrite in PHP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is my Blog page's url

```
www.mysite.com/blog/?id=1
www.mysite.com/blog/?id=2
www.mysite.com/blog/?id=3
```

But I want to look my url look like

```
www.mysite.com/blog/1
www.mysite.com/blog/2
www.mysite.com/blog/3
```

I used the following Rewriting in the `.htaccess`.

But I am getting **Error 404** from my System.(Though the subdirectory /blog is there)

What is the mistake done by me and How can i fix this ?

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ blog/?id=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ blog/?id=$1
```

Comment: `$1` is probably *blog/1* or something. Try `RewriteRule ^blog/([0-9]+)$ blog/?id=$1`.

Comment: "Not working" doesn't mean anything. What exactly are you doing, what exactly is the result you expect, and what result are you getting instead? You've shown us a piece of code, but you're not clarifying what exactly you're doing to "test" this.

Comment: voila https://www.dropbox.com/s/uf5kfxqmj17vitt/Screenshot%202014-07-02%2015.34.58.png

your htaccess is fine!

source: htaccess.madewithlove.be

Comment: "Not Working" in this place means. "Object Not Found" -> Every programmer knows it.

Comment: "Object Not Found"? Where does that come from? The web server? Your system? Have you looked at error logs? Details, man, details!

Comment: What type of system is it? A CMS? if so which one? That can matter sometimes because they have special ways of routing URL in some CMS's. Object not found doesn't sound like it comes from Apache.

Comment: Nope, I am just using in the custom php.

Comment: If I am reading this correctly, your rewrite rule is catching _everything_ and sticking it after `blog/id=`, so if you go to `www.mysite.com/blog/1`, it would send you to `www.mysite.com/blog/id=/blog/1`

Comment: Oh, then how can i make it www.mysite.com/blog/?id=1 ?

Comment: Well, try the answer from @Sum - it might need slight tweaking but overall it looks more correct. Unfortunately, my .htaccess-foo is rusty, I can't remember the correct syntax (I seem to recall modifiers being relevant, and `[L]` seems familiar) but the documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteRule) should help you more than I can at the moment.

Comment: @vid Thanks the sum's answer worked greatly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not good in english, but here i can try to answer.

look like your blog is on a sub dir.
so,

RewriteRule ^blog/([^/]*)$ /blog/?id=$1 [L]

and try to add

RewriteBase /

if you still have problem,
also..
there are many generator for htaccess
for example
http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php

Comment: I'm trying generateit.net.

Answer (score 1):

I spent almost two days last year chasing this one!

Many Linux distroes (at least Debian-based) prevent you from using a .htaccess file to override the Apache configuration files by stating `AllowOverride None` in the default config file.

You can change the line to `AllowOverride All` by editing `/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default`

Hope this helps.

Comment: But, i have to do it in for a single Folder alone.

Comment: Do you have admin privileges on the server?

Comment: Right now, I am doing it in the System.

Comment: Sorry! I made a serious typo! AllowOverride All in global config will do the trick. — This will allow the .htaccess file to work.

Comment: Just remember to reload or restart Apache in the meantime.

Comment: Yes I agree, But any idea in .htaccess ReWrite Rule ? and Yes, I do restart the Apache in every actions.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly check **mod_rewrite is enabled on apache**:
Then add the following to your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?blog/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ /blog?id=$1 [L]
```

Also check  **AllowOverride All** is given in the directory for this module in apache.
Following link can be useful:

[AllowOverride for .htaccess on local machine giving 403 Forbidden](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5737048/allowoverride-for-htaccess-on-local-machine-giving-403-forbidden)

Answer (score 1):

This is called `Pretty URL's` or `SEO Friendly URLs`, this can be achieved by several ways.

One way is doing everything yourself and modifying the .htaccess to look something like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^users/(\d+)*$ ./profile.php?id=$1
RewriteRule ^threads/(\d+)*$ ./thread.php?id=$1

RewriteRule ^search/(.*)$ ./search.php?query=$1
```

Note that this requires your webserver to be **Apache**.

Other ways (which actually work somewhat the same) is by using PHP Frameworks which often have Routing with Pretty URL's implemented so you don't have to reinvent the wheel.

This is Laravel's approach of creating routes and pretty url's:

```
Route::get('/blog/{id}', function() {
    // Do something
});
```

Take a look at Laravel: http://www.laravel.com. I really love this framework and its features.

**Ruby on Rails** has this implemented by default as well. But I assume you are not using it since you are programming PHP.

For a good tutorial explaining how to create Pretty URL's within PHP yourself take a look at this tutorial from TutsPlus: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/using-htaccess-files-for-pretty-urls--net-6049

Hope I helped you! Good luck.